# Reverse Inside Parentheses

Tags: python, python-3.x, reverse

Hi guys I need some help with a python script.

Inside of the parantheses need to be reversed alternately. I've been struggling with this for over 2 hours...

```
def reverse(string):
    counter = 0
    res = [""]
    for i in string:
            
        if i == "(":
            res.append("")
            counter = counter + 1
            print(res, counter)
                
        elif i == ")":
            counter = counter - 1
                
            if counter % 2 == 0:
                res[counter] += res.pop()
                print(res, counter)
            else:
                res[counter] = res[counter] + res.pop()  
                print(res, counter)       
        elif counter % 2 == 0:
            res[counter] += i
            print(res, counter)
        else:
            res[counter] = i + res[counter]
            print(res, counter)
    return res[0]
```

```
INPUT: E(ev(ry)ht)i(gn)
EXPECTED OUTPUT: Everything

OUTPUT:
['E', 'very'] 1
['E', 'hvery'] 1
['E', 'thvery'] 1
['Ethvery'] 0
['Ethveryi'] 0
['Ethveryi', ''] 1
['Ethveryi', 'g'] 1
['Ethveryi', 'ng'] 1
['Ethverying'] 0
```

I'd really appreciate if you helped.

Comment: Do you want to know : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python or do you want to know what is wrong with your code?

Comment: I want to make it so the word doesn't get jumbled up in the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through the input string and add the character to a `list` as long as the examined character is not a parenthesis. If the examined character is a parenthesis, you need to know if the number of parentheses seen so far is even or odd. If it is even, you can add the characters in the `list` to the result. If it is odd, you have to add the characters in the `list` reversed to the result. In either case, you empty the `list`, and need to take care that it's empty before you return your result.

```py
>>> def reverse(a_string):
...     seen_even = True
...     temp, result = [], []
...     for c in a_string:
...         if c not in ('(',')'):
...            temp.append(c)
...         else:
...            if seen_even:
...                result.extend(temp)
...            else:
...                result.extend(temp[::-1])
...            seen_even = not seen_even
...            temp = []
...     if temp: # e.g., 'Everything', 'Everythi)gn'
...         if seen_even:
...             result.extend(temp)
...         else:
...             result.extend(temp[::-1])
...     return ''.join(result)
... 
>>> inp_string = 'E(ev(ry)ht)i(gn)'
>>> reverse(inp_string)
'Everything'
```